# get and display one image in a stack of 3 channel images, in a numpy array

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib, imshow

I have a stack of images. The first one on the stack looks like this:

[image]

```
import dicom as dc
dcm = dc.read_file('full_stack.dcm')
dcm = dcm.pixel_array
print type(dcm)
print dcm.shape
```

This gives me

```
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>

(3, 180, 480, 640)
```

So it looks like there are:

- 3 channels
- 180 images
- width is 480
- height is 640

Great.

My goal is to extract an image in the stack. Then, I want to display that image. Sounds simple enough.

This is my strategy. I would love any ideas/feedback on this:

1) Get one image. Use basic slicing to get the 10th image on the stack

```
dcm1 = dcm[0:, 10:11]
dcm1.shape
(3, 1, 480, 640)
```

2) To use `plt.imshow` to actually plot this in pyplot, we need this shape:  (r, c, channels). So I guess beat the image up by brute force.

```
dcm2 = np.squeeze(dcm1, axis=1)  # throw away the '1'...this makes me nervous
print 'threw away the "1":              ', dcm2.shape
dcm3 = np.swapaxes(dcm2, 0,2)
print 'swapped the first and last dim:  ', dcm3.shape
dcm4 = np.swapaxes(dcm3, 0,1)
print 'swapped the first and second dim:', dcm4.shape
```

Now, I've mangled this poor image as such:

```
threw away the "1":               (3, 480, 640)
swapped the first and last dim:   (640, 480, 3)
swapped the first and second dim: (480, 640, 3)
```

Time for plotting! What could possibly go wrnog?

`imgplot = plt.imshow(dcm4)`

Here's what I get:

[image]

Somehow my image now has all kinds of color and looks terrible.

Here's where my question starts -- does anyone know what happened? Clearly my methodology was unsophisticated and unsatisfying. But I'm not sure exactly where to go.

*extra stuff, probably not really relevant*

At this point, I tried to hack the channels down to one, then duplicate back up to three so that `imshow` could read it, and I'll save you the details but it gave me this:

[image]

Comment: Questions on Stackoverflow should be reproducible, see [mcve]. So you may find more help when supplying some sample data or at least link to it, such that people can test this

Comment: If I remember correctly, dicom images are usually in hounsfield units. Are you sure you're loading only `uint8` values in your array?

Comment: For CT only or also ultrasounds? I'll have to look into this! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This solution works fine for me. Please verify the range of values in your input array is in `0-255` range and as `uint8` datatype. Dimensions alone are not enough for reproducing the result. For example, the following setup works fine for me:

```
In [50]: img = np.random.randint(0, 255, (3, 180, 480, 640), dtype=np.uint8)
In [51]: img1 = np.squeeze(img[:, 9:10])

# proper_img is a *view*; caution while modifying it
In [52]: proper_img = np.moveaxis(img1, source=0, destination=-1)
In [53]: plt.imshow(proper_img)
```

And the plot that I get is below:

[image]

Comment: I pass both the range and datatype test. I think my image just might be corrupted. :(  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck yeah, that's also highly likely. try loading some other images :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know anything about dicom images and I have no file to test this, but I would imagine that a simple transpose operation should give you the desired output as

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(3,1,480,640)
b = np.transpose(a[:,0,:,:], axes=[1,2,0])
print (b.shape) # (480L, 640L, 3L)
```

Comment: Using your recommendation I still get my unicorn-puke image. I'm starting to think this is not a retractable problem.

Comment: Speaking of "retractable", questions on Stackoverflow should be reproducible, see [mcve]. So you may find more help when supplying some sample data or at least link to it, such that people can test this.